# Laravel mocking route parameters

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, mockery

I am currently unit testing some of my form validation and need to mock a route parameter so that it can pass the tests. I've set up what I thought was the right expectation for the request but I've not done something correctly.

```
Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route('user')->id)
```

This is the test mock that I'm attempting to get to pass. Everything I"m attempting to do turns up as that the user property on the route is null.

```
$userMock = $this->mock(User::class)->expects()->set('id', 1);

$requestMock = $this->mock(Request::class)
        ->makePartial()
        ->shouldReceive('route')
        ->set('user', $user)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(\Mockery::self());

$this->mock(Rule::class, function ($mock) use ($userMock, $requestMock) {
    $mock->expects()->unique('user')->andReturns(\Mockery::self());
    $mock->expects()->ignore($requestMock)->andReturns(\Mockery::self());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not testing as you should:

- When you test something that is related to the Laravel's core, you [`Feature test`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#making-requests).
- When you want to test your own `class` or a `Job` or a [`Command`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/console-tests#introduction), you `Unit test` (you can either use PHPUnit's test case or Laravel's test case, so in the latter case, you load and have the framework available, I use this 99% of the time).
- When you want to test an external API (even if it is `localhost` but it is other system), you do `Integration tests`.

So, I will write a *Feature test* showing you what you should have done, so have in mind that I am going to write fake routes and factories that maybe you have set differently or didn't even set up (I will be using `Laravel 8` and `PHP 8`):

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ShowTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_error_is_thrown_when_user_is_not_unique()
    {
        /**
         * Create a fake user so we have an
         * existing user in the DB because
         * that is what we want to test
         *
         * This should end up as last_name = Doe
         */
        User::factory()->create([
            'last_name' => $lastName = 'Doe'
        ]);

        /**
         * This is going to be our
         * logged in user and we will
         * send this data.
         *
         * Fake last_name so we do not
         * end up with Doe when faker runs.
         * 
         * @var User $ownUser
         */
        $ownUser = User::factory()->create(['last_name' => 'Lee']);

        /**
         * We will simulate sending an update
         * so we can change the last_name of
         * our logged in user, but there is
         * another user with the same last name
         */
        $response = $this->actingAs($ownUser)
            ->put("/fake/route/{$ownUser->id}", ['last_name' => $lastName]);

        /**
         * If you don't want to assert what error
         * is coming back, just
         * write ...Errors('last_name') but I
         * recommend checking what is giving back
         */
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors(['last_name' => 'Literal expected error string.']);
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I am testing here. If you have any more questions, please ask.

Also, if you can share your real code, I can write tests with you and try to have your code 100% tested.

Comment: laravel don't have integration test by default, so where can I make them?

Comment: @free2idol1 depends what you refer to integration tests, do you need UI testing or just e2e? I am not a guru related to e2e testing, when you need UI testing, but then, it is just a "feature" test in a different namespace, and you literally test that you have all your config (or environment) correctly set, and run the test so it does make the real request to that external system